# How do I get Excel to display date/time in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?

Tags: excel, date, datetime, time, format

This is driving me crazy. I have two columns, one is date in yyyy-mm-dd format and one is time in hh:mm:ss format. When I try to make a new column combining them into one cell as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss using =text(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")+text(C2, "hh:mm:ss") it gives me the date format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm - i.e. it doesn't include the ss. I don't see the option for yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in the format cells window, does excel just not support this format? I would appreciate any help, I put in an example below of my data.

```
Date         Time          DateTime
2021-07-06   03:33:33      2021-07-06 03:33
2021-07-07   15:55:12      2021-07-07 15:55
2021-07-08   21:18:12      2021-07-08 12:18
```

Comment: Also, I don't care if Excel acknowledges the format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, if I can just get it as text that works too, but when I try to combine them as just text values it gives the date and time to me in the datevalue and timevalue formats.

Comment: Don't use `TEXT`, just add them together and then change the *format* of the cell, using the custom format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: Wow thank you I didn't realize you could add a custom format although that should've been glaringly obvious. Thanks again.